# I am creating a system and my console says one of my functions are undefined

Tags: javascript

I've been looking for an answer for this problem, but I feel like I need a much more in depth response from people, as I am a beginner to programming. Can someone please look over my code, and maybe test it out to identify my problem? My console keeps saying my addComment() function isn't defined. Here is my code:

```
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <p>Name:</p> <input type="text" id="Name"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <p>Text:</p> 
        <textarea rows="10" cols="25" id="Text"></textarea> 
        <input id="Post" type="submit" value="Post" onclick="return addCom()"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <h1 class="section">COMMENTS</h1>
    </section>

    <script>
        var Post = document.getElementById("Post");
        var Text = document.getElementById("Text").value;
        var Name = document.getElementById("Name").value;

        window.onload = function addCom() {
            document.createElement("div").innerHTML = Name + "says:" + Text;
        }
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Please identify my problems and let me know. It would be appreciated if you could tell me why my console kept saying my function wasn't defined. Thank you.

Regards, 
   Amiya

Comment: Well, `addComment` is neither defined nor invoked anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: @CertainPerformance While it isn't defined, it is certainly invoked.  The submit button.

Comment: @CertainPerformance pretty obvious OP meant their `addCom` function, which is both defined and invoked.

Comment: @Amiya Simply giving the function a name isn't the same as defining it.  You attached the definition to a handler, rather than doing what you intended.  Simply define it somewhere else, like say: `function addCom() { /* do stuff */ };`, then assign that function to both the handler and onload event: `window.onload = addCom;`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript named function expressions - scope accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446646/javascript-named-function-expressions-scope-accessibility)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few things that jump out from your code.

First, why are you setting `window.onLoad` to your function?  I assume you don't want your function run when the page loads, but instead when the user clicks your button?

```
window.onload = function addCom() {
    document.createElement("div").innerHTML = Name + "says:" + Text;
}
```

should be

```
function addCom() {
    document.createElement("div").innerHTML = Name + "says:" + Text;
}
```

Second, you are pulling the values from your form into the variables `Post`, `Text` and `Name` at *the moment you load the page* when you likely want to pull these values when the user clicks the button (ie: after they have entered values).  You can do this by moving these into your function, like so:

```
<script>
    function addCom() {
        var Post = document.getElementById("Post");
        var Text = document.getElementById("Text").value;
        var Name = document.getElementById("Name").value;

        document.createElement("div").innerHTML = Name + "says:" + Text;
    }
</script>
```

Third, your function doesn't actually *do* much.  It creates an element, sets its `innerHTML` value, but then... nothing.  You need to *do something* with your new element.  Try this:

```
function addCom() {
    var Post = document.getElementById("Post");
    var Text = document.getElementById("Text").value;
    var Name = document.getElementById("Name").value;

    var el = document.createElement("div");
    el.innerHTML = Name + "says:" + Text;
    document.body.appendChild(el); // add the new element to the page
}
```

Here is a snippet showing the final working example:

```html
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <p>Name:</p> <input type="text" id="Name"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <p>Text:</p> 
        <textarea rows="10" cols="25" id="Text"></textarea> 
        <input id="Post" type="submit" value="Post" onclick="return addCom()"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <h1 class="section">COMMENTS</h1>
    </section>

    <script>

    function addCom() {
        var Post = document.getElementById("Post");
        var Text = document.getElementById("Text").value;
        var Name = document.getElementById("Name").value;
      
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.innerHTML = Name + "says:" + Text;
        document.body.appendChild(el);
    }
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/hikolilume/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: Thank you very much. The "window.onload" was for another function I was going to create, but I had made a mistake and put it there. I would also like to thank you for pointing out my innerHTML mistake, because that was my biggest problem. I've also left off a bit of my code because I had made an onclick event, but I must have not shown that.