# How to access value returned from a function expression?

Tags: javascript, function, expression

I'm trying to return and access the value of a dynamic select from `onchange` event. I know how to work with function declarations but function expressions are unclear to me. A little help would be appreciated.

js

```
//create select
var select = document.createElement('select');
select.setAttribute('id','select_month');
//onchange
select.onchange = function changeMonth(selectedmonth){
selectedmonth = this.value;//works well here
return selectedmonth;
};

var selectedmonth = changeMonth();//undefined
```

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+scope+of+named+function+expression) of [javascript named function expressions - scope accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17446646/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`changeMonth` is a variable that is scoped only to the function itself, and is therefore not available to the rest of the script.

Even if it *was* available, then realise that when that function is called by the DOM (when the event fires), it calls it with `this` bound to the DOM element. When *you* call it explicitly in your code, you should do the same.

The good thing is that the reference to the function is available as `select.onchange`, so use that. That way you solve both issues at the same time:

```
var selectedmonth = select.onchange(select);
```

Comment: I get ReferenceError: changeMonth is not defined

Comment: Indeed, corrected.